# searching for sysvinit in a linux tree

Tags: linux, source, sysvinit

This is the tree for petalinux.

https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/tree/xlnx_3.8

I am looking for sysvinit package,which contains things like init ,halt etc. When this source code is compiled we get corresponding binaries in /sbin/. I found after compiling binary files like init.sysvinit,halt.sysvinit etc.

I can download the source code separately from [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/sysvinit/)  But the same package must be there in petlainux source also.   How do I search these source code in petalinux tree above?

Comment: Can't say for sure but I think based on **[a quick check](http://xgoogle.xilinx.com/search?getfields=*&numgm=5&filter=0&proxystylesheet=xilinx&client=xilinx&site=EntireSite&btnG=Google+Search&output=xml_no_dtd&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&requiredfields=-Archived%3Atrue&q=busybox&submit2.x=0&submit2.y=0&submit2=Search&lang2search=)** that petalinux perhaps uses **[busybox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox#Features)** in place of sysvinit.  Note that most normal linux distributions, other than debian, don't use sysvinit anymore (but they don't use busybox either).

Comment: Is Busybox an alternate to Sysvinit? And yes I have seen an option for busybox in the Configuration GUI of petalinux

Comment: Yes (it's more than just that though).  Sysvinit is a specific implementation of the **[init daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)** fundamental to all *nix style systems; busybox can serve a similar purpose. Init is the first process started by the kernel during boot.

Answer (score 1):

You [linked](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/tree/xlnx_3.8) to a Linux kernel source tree. You won't find sysvinit there (nor any other program) because this is only the kernel, not a complete Linux distribution.

This [Xilinx repository collection](https://github.com/Xilinx/) doesn't include sysvinit or any other init that I can find. The [wiki](http://xilinx.wikidot.com/zynq-rootfs) mentions using [BusyBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) for userland tools, and says to download the upstream sources. BusyBox includes an init program.